# Проверить генерик-тип интерфейса в C#?

Tags: c#, .net, рефлексия, .net-core

У меня есть тип AType который реализует генерик-интерфейс `IA<BType>`
Тип `BType` реализует интерфейс `IC`.
Как я могу проверить связан `AType` с `IC` или нет?

```cs
class AType : IA<BType>
{}

class BType : IC
{}

interface IA<T>
{ }

interface IC
{ }
```

Тип `BType` может быть любым и мне о нем ничего неизвестно. У меня есть экземпляр `AType` и мне нужно понять реализует ли он `IC` через generic тип промежуточного интерфейса `IA`
Проверка ниже не работает:

```
var aInstance = new AType();
aInstance is IA<IC> // false
...
```

Также для `Type.IsAssignableFrom(Type)`

```cs
typeof(IC).IsAssignableFrom(aInstance.GetType()) // false
```

Comment: Это Stack Overflow **на русском**. Переведите вопрос или удалите его и откройте заново на enSO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Проверка ниже не работает:

Верно, потому что компилятор ничего не знает о вариантности интерфейса.

Если ваш интерфейс `IA<T>` фактически является ковариантным, то укажите это явно:

```
interface IA<out T> { }
```

потом:

```
var aInstance = new AType();
Console.WriteLine(aInstance is IA<IC>); // True
```

Но явная вариантность — это ограничение и интерфейс может считаться ковариантным только в случае когда все его члены используют тип `T` только для возврата.
Скомпилируется:

```
interface IA<out T>
{
    T Method();
}
```

Не скомпилируется:

```
interface IA<out T>
{
    void Method(T t);
}
```

<sub>подробно: [Вариативность в универсальных интерфейсах (C#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/variance-in-generic-interfaces)</sub>

Если ваш тип не является ковариантным, то вам придется разбирать это явно.

Для проверок внутри класса можно написать что-то вроде:

```
class AType<T> : IA<T>
{
    public bool HasParamenterOfTypeIC()
    {
        return typeof(IC).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T));
    }
}
```

тогда:

```
var a = new AType<BType>();
Console.WriteLine(a.HasParamenterOfTypeIC()); // True

var b = new AType<object>();
Console.WriteLine(b.HasParamenterOfTypeIC()); // False
```

для проверок снаружи вы должны еще и явно достать дженерик-параметр и проверить его на совместимость:

```
class OType : IA<object> { }

class AType : IA<BType> { }

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(HasParamenterOfTypeIC(typeof(AType))); // True
        Console.WriteLine(HasParamenterOfTypeIC(typeof(OType))); // False
    }

    static bool HasParamenterOfTypeIC(Type type)
    {
        return type
            .GetInterfaces()
            .SelectMany(i => i.GetGenericArguments())
            .Any(i => typeof(IC).IsAssignableFrom(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: все типы являются типами библиотек, поэтому не одно решение с изменением типов не подошло. Однако извлечение генерик-параметра с помощью GetGenericArguments() и проверка его на совместимость прошла, спасибо